# How to access global service objects (injection-like)?

Tags: python, flask

I am rather new to flask but what I mean by the title is I want to create a service object which can be used in all controllers or services.

In Java (Spring) I would create a `@Bean`:

```java
@Configuration
public class WhateverGatewayBeans {

    @Value("{whatever.api.key}")
    public String apiKey;

    @Bean
    public WhateverGateway getWhateverGateway() {
        return new WhateverGateway(apiKey)
    }
}
```

Which I can now use in all my `@Service`s:

```java
@Service
public class AnyService {

    private final WhateverGateway whateverGateway;

    @Autowired // Using injection
    public AnyService(WhateverGateway whateverGateway) {
        this.whateverGateway = whateverGateway;
    }

    public Something getSomethingFromWhatever(String param) {
        return this.whateverGateway.getSomething(param);
    }
}
```

And so on

```java
@Controller
public class AnyController {

    private final AnyService anyService;

    @Autowired
    public AnyController(AnyService anyService) {
        this.anyService = anyService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/api/whatever")
    public Something getSomething(@QueryParam("param") String param) {
        return this.anyService.getSomething(param);
    }
}
```

> Please note that the above code was written on the fly and likely to be not 100% correct but you get the idea

I am looking for something similar in Flask:

```
@app.route('/api/something')
def get_something(whatever_gateway):
    param = request.args.get('param')
    return whatever_gateway.get_something_from_whatever(param)
```

Here, `whatever_gateway` should be fully initialized during the server startup. Imagine it has to load for some time, the server should not be up before `whatever_gateway` is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you instantiate your gateway at module level:

```
# gateways.py
whatever_gateway = WhateverGateway()
```

And then just import:

```
from gateways import whatever_gateway

@app.route('/api/something')
def get_something(whatever_gateway):
    param = request.args.get('param')
    return whatever_gateway.get_something_from_whatever(param)
```

There were however other solutions around for dependency injection or you can roll your own. I did it once and it was easy. However later on I realised that most of the time you can get away with just using modules as shown above.

If it takes a while to instantiate the gateway, you can delay that to increase app startup time by wrapping it in some sort of factory:

```
gateway = None

def get_gateway():
    global gateway
    if not gateway:
        gateway = WhateverGateway()
    return gateway
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. By now I realized that I can also place this into `app.config['whatever']` and get it back from `current_app.config['whatever']`. I guess that does not make a difference? Except conceptually because "whatever" is not really part of any configuration ..

Comment: Yes you can do that. You can even attach it to the app itself, like `app.services['whatever'] = WhateverGateway()` if you prefer, but there's really no need to. Just import it at module level. Also, i updated my answer to show how you can delay gateway instantiation by using a factory function.